# Unable to start systemmd service

Tags: systemd, python, autostart

I run a logger collecting data using a Python script. Currently using a tmux, so I can detach and close the ssh tunnel. I would prefer it to start at the systemstart.

I've followed [this recipe](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/linux/auto-start-python-script-on-boot-systemd/) to the letter, except that instead of the example Python script, I've inserted my own. Apart from that I followed it exactly, even including the script and directory names etc.

Here is the recipe (since external references might get lost):

## Create a Systemd Entry

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/myapp.service
```

> ```
> [Unit]
> # After=network.service
> Description=My App
>
> [Service]
> Type=simple
> # WorkingDirectory=/code/python/myapp
> ExecStart=/code/scripts/myapp.sh
> # User=do-user
>
> [Install]
> WantedBy=multi-user.target
> # WantedBy=default.target
> ```

## Create Bash Script

```
nano /code/scripts/myapp.sh
```

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> # cd /code/python/myapp python3 /code/python/myapp/run.py >> /code/logs/myapp.log 2>&1 mkdir /code/logs
> ```

## Create Python Script

```
nano /code/python/myapp/run.py
```

> ```
> import signal import time import datetime
>
> is_shutdown = False
>
> def stop(sig, frame):   print(f"SIGTERM at {datetime.datetime.now()}") global is_shutdown   is_shutdown = True
>
> def ignore(sig, frsma):   print(f"SIGHUP at {datetime.datetime.now()}")
>
> signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, stop) signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, ignore)
>
> print(f"START at {datetime.datetime.now()}")
>
> while not is_shutdown:   print('.', end='', flush=True)   time.sleep(1)
>
> print(f"END at {datetime.datetime.now()}")
> ```

## Test Systemd

**Set file permission**

```
sudo chmod 744 /code/scripts/myapp.sh
sudo chmod 664 /etc/systemd/system/myapp.service
```

**Enable Service**

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable myapp.service
```

**Test Service**

```
sudo systemctl start myapp.service
```

**Check Status**

```
sudo systemctl start status.service
```

**Check Log**

```
tail -f /code/logs/myapp.log
```

However, when I attempt to start the service I get this error:

```
$ sudo chmod 744 /code/scripts/myapp.sh
$ sudo chmod 664 /etc/systemd/system/myapp.service
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl enable myapp.service
$ sudo systemctl start myapp.service
$ sudo systemctl start status.service
Failed to start status.service: Unit status.service not found.
$ tail -f /code/logs/myapp.log
...
```

The logs located at `/code/logs/myapp.log` are empty. In an earlier attempt, the logs contained a module import error. I've changed the script slightly, since then the logs remain empty.

This is the OS I use on the Edge Device on which the Logger runs:

Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-147-generic x86_64)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You want to start `myapp.service`, yet you start `status.service` via `sudo systemctl start status.service`. Is this merely a typo or already the problem? Please also put your script in the question - external references might get lost or change sooner or later. What is status.service to myapp.service? Does it even exist? (seemingly not)

Comment: Agree with @FelixJN looks like a typo. I any case, I would remove the bash script and and run directly the Python script from systemd.  Just add `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the beginning of the Python script file.